# Ruby data structure to render a certain JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
[
   {
      "id":"123",
      "name":"House"
   },
   {
      "id":"1456",
      "name":"Desperate Housewives"
   },
   {
      "id":"789",
      "name":"Dollhouse"
   },
   {
      "id":"10",
      "name":"Full House"
   }
]
```

How can I render to produce this JSON format from within Ruby? I have all the data from the DB (@result) and don't know what data structure to use in Ruby that will render to this when I do this:

```
respond_to do |format|    
    format.json { render :json => @result}
end
```

What data structure should @result be and how can I iterate to produce it? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `@result` is an array of ActiveRecord model instances then `render :json => @result` will produce something like what you are after, but will include all the attributes of the model (`render` calls `to_json` on the object you pass it unless it is a string).

To only include the id and name attributes, you can use the `:only` parameter of [`to_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873):

```
respond_to do |format|    
  format.json { render :json => @result.to_json(:only => [:id, :name] }
end
```

Alternatively, you can create a array of Hash objects that only contain the required attributes:

```
respond_to do |format|    
  format.json { render :json => 
                  @result.collect {|o| {:id => o.id, :name => o.name} } }
end
```

*Edit:* See @dt's comment below. There is an attribute in the model named text that needs to be output as name. This can be done by creating an alias for text in the model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_method :name, :text
```

and including the name using `:methods`:

```
respond_to do |format|    
  format.json { render :json => @result.to_json(:only => :id, :methods => :name }
end
```

Alternatively, the array of hashes approach can be used to rename the attribute:

```
respond_to do |format|    
  format.json { render :json => 
                  @result.collect {|o| {:id => o.id, :name => o.text} } }
end
```

Comment: thank you, that is almost it, but the issue is that the results I get from ActiveRecord do not have the :name attribute, so essentially I need to loop through it and reassign my attribute (text) to name, so I think I need maybe to create a hash inside the for/do loop and then add it to an array?

@simianarmy suggests something close, but i don't know how to iterate to create that. does the order matter? when I print it out it always puts name before id. will that matter?

@evgeny I have the gem installed, thank you!

thank you. each answer is helpful!

Comment: Whether or not 'id' comes before 'name' does not matter.

Comment: @dt There are two options: 1) Add a method called `name` to your model and then call `@result.to_json(:only => :id, :methods => :name)`. 2) Modify the `collect` statement to rename the attribute: `@result.collect {|o| {:id => o.id, :name => o.text}}. The order of the attributes in the output will be dependent on how Hash orders the keys, but shouldn't be important to anything parsing the JSON output.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [json gem](http://flori.github.com/json/). It will allow to you do things like

```
@result.to_json
```

to convert your structures (say, a Hash) to json format. If you're using Ruby on Rails, this functionality should already be accessible to you, so just create a Hash and call to_json.

Answer (score 0):

To create a JSON object of that particular format, you need a ruby array containing hashes for its elements.

```
@result = [{:id => "10", :name => "Full House"}, {:id => "789", :name => "blahblah"},...]
```

Rails will convert the ruby array to json correctly in your render response block:

```
respond_to do |format|    
  format.json { render :json => @result}
end
```

Comment: resultsarray = []
     
     for r in @result
        resultshash = {:id => r.id, :name => r.text}
        resultsarray<<resultshash
      end

each time i do this, it puts the name first, so that the json returned is in the wrong order. will that matter? it's not working, so i think that could be it?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a jQuery plugin (FCBKComplete) that needed the json results with specific key names, specifically 'caption' and 'value', which did not exist in the array I was calling `to_json` on.

So I did this (hacky, but it works):

```
render :json => taggings.map { |t| {:caption => t.tag.name, :value => t.tag.name} }.to_json
```

Where `taggings` is an array returned by an ActiveRecord find, and that returns json like so:

```
[{"value":"tag.a","caption":"tag.a"},{"value":"tag.b","caption":"tag.b"}]
```